# Can Lua do an arithmetic right shift?

Tags: lua

Take a look at the following code:

```
x = -27
y = 3
print(x >> y)
```

This prints `2305843009213693948`. Since there is no sign bit, Lua seems to have done a logical right shift instead of an arithmetic one. When I do the following in C, I get `-4` instead, which is approximately `-27/8`.

```
int64 x = -27;
int64 y = 3;
int64 z = x >> y;
```

Is there a way to do the same in Lua?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use integer division instead: `-27//8` gives `-4`.

Comment: This indeed returns `-4` but shouldn't integer division rather return `-3`? In C I get `-3` as well when doing integer division...

Comment: @Andreas - `math.modf(-27/8)` equals to `-3`

Comment: @Andreas, this is due to operator precedence: `-27//8` is the same as `(-27)//8` and gives `-4`
, whereas `-(27//8)`does give `-3`.